# CakePHP - How can I switch databases on the fly? (CakePHP 1.1.x)

Tags: php, database, cakephp, dynamic

While we're trying to upgrade our system to a newer version of CakePHP where it's easier to switch between databases, I currently have to get the 1.1.x version able to switch between databases.

I've tried using the fairly simple method shown on [this post](http://insanityville.com/2010/04/how-to-switch-between-databases-in-cakephp-on-the-fly/), however I can't get this fully working. Debuging the `$connected` object does reveal all the information of the database I'm trying to save to, yet when I save something to the database I still end up changing the original database and not the second database. Anyone know of a method I can use to switch databases on cakePHP 1.1 or what might be going wrong with the method given on the site posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this url:-

http://insanityville.com/2010/04/how-to-switch-between-databases-in-cakephp-on-the-fly/

**Read it**

I'm pretty sure some of the functions I used are specific to 1.2.
But you can try. I'll give you a basic overview of what I did.

I made a componant, and inside the componant in the initialize
method.. I do this:
(all the connection data is stored in a Client Model, that I load with
loadModel)

```
     $newDb =& ConnectionManager::create('myconn_name',
array('driver' => 'mysql'
                ,'host' => $client->data['Client']['db_host']
                ,'login' => $client->data['Client']['db_login']
                ,'password' => $client->data['Client']['db_password']
                ,'database' => $client->data['Client']['db_name']
                ,'persistent' => false
```

And then in my app_model I set

```
 var $useDbConfig = 'myconn_name';
```

Again, I'm not sure at all how well this will work in 1.1

Comment: This does actually work. The functions you use are used in the 1.1 API. I had seen a similar solution, but something in our system was preventing it from working. If someone else checks this looking for the answer, and if you're code is failing due to missing functions, go to the 1.1 API documentation. All the functions were there and this works successfully.

Thanks!